# C# trying to create a forest simulation.(Timers, Inheritance, 2D array)

Tags: c#

I have a C# application that does the following. 
Firstly before i start, my application is a Forest simulation that is represented as a flat 2D rectangle. and inside the 2D there are (Spaces) of size 10 x 10 and are separated by a margin.

the forest contains animals, and the animals that exist are lions & elephants.
the forest also contains Rocks and trees.

the forest is handled by an event tick, which is called when a button is clicked.
when i click the btn_draw. i am supposed to draw the forest with randomly allocated forest Elements(subclasses).

My problem is here, firstly i have a class called ForestDrawingClass inside it are 2 methods.

```
`public class ForestDrawingClass : DrawingForest_Form
{
    int width { get; set; }
    int height { get; set; }

    ForestDrawingClass(int w, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void createTheForest()
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush mybrush2D = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen);

        g.FillRectangle(mybrush2D, 0, 15, width, height);
    }

    public void addEmptySpace()
    {
        int draw_W = (int)(width * 0.0644);
        int draw_H = (int)(height * 0.0625);
        int w = 10;
        int h = 10;
        int xposition = w + w / 2;
        int yposition = h + h / 2;
        SolidBrush mybrushOpenSpace = new SolidBrush(Color.ForestGreen);
        int x = w / 2; int y = h / 2;


        for (int i = 0; i < (draw_H * draw_W); i++)
        {
            if (i % draw_W == 0)
            {
                x = 5;
                y += yposition;
            }
            g.FillRectangle(mybrushOpenSpace, x, y, w, h);
            x += xposition;`
```

**this code seems to compile well, but how can i call these methods when i hit the button that is supposed to start a timer**. 
how do you call these methods from within the form. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does `ForestDrawingClass` inherit from `DrawingForest_Form`? You need to provide a full [mcve] for us to work from. We should be able to copy, paste, and run your code with minimal effort on our behalf.

Comment: BTW, you're creating a lot of objects that are `IDisposable`. You need to dispose them when they're done.

Answer (score 0):

Place a Timer Control onto the form assuming this is WinForm.

Timer Controls have a Tick event that fire each x milliseconds based on the Elapsed property.

You start and stop the Timer Control using it's enabled property.

So in code:

```
private void btn_draw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //Call your Forest Render
}
```

I recommend you use the Forms_Paint event instead of a Timer.

Comment: alright basically i have 2 forms, first form i input into a numeric updown the Width and Height. So how do i call these values in the second form, and how to I initialze the constructor of the class. Its making me dizzy think about a solution,

Comment: for example i do this:
   private void Display_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             ForestIteration.Enabled = true;
            
         }

       
        private void ForestIteration_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ForestDrawingClass forest = new ForestDrawingClass(10,10);
            forest.createTheForest();
            forest.addEmptySpace();

        }

**Nothing gets Displayed**

Comment: Use the `Paint` event instead.